# Ionic 3, "push" de variáveis

Tags: typescript, ionic3

Boa tarde pessoal, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa dúvida básica ? como faço pra pegar a variável de um arquivo ts e jogar ela num outro arquivo ? exemplo...
em um dos typescript tenho uma variável que recebe o valor dado através dessa função... eu queria que após essa variável recebesse o valor, ela fosse pra outra pagina .ts também !!! Como seria possivel ? Obrigado desde já !!!

Comment: mas você quer passar o valor e mudar a pagina né?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu entendi que você quer ir de uma página A para uma página B e levar valores de A para B. Se for isso, utilize o `NavController` e `NavParams`.

Exemplo:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PaginaB } from 'caminho/para/seu/component/PaginaB';
export class PaginaA {
  private variavel: string = "Valor a ser passado para PaginaB";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  private irParaPaginaB(){
    this.navCtrl.push(PaginaB, {parametro: this.variavel})
  }
}
```

Na sua Página B

```
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

export class PaginaB{
  private variavel: string;
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     this.variavel = navParams.get('parametro');
  }
}
```

De uma olhada na [documentação](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)